# Blocked a prezi iframe. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, prezi

I'm now on localhost, trying to embed a prezi presentation to my website. I get the following error message. How do I solve it?

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://prezi.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Code:

```
<iframe 
    src="http://prezi.com/embed/auxybvbmwavk/?bgcolor=ffffff&amp;
    lock_to_path=1&amp;
    autoplay=0&amp;
    autohide_ctrls=0&amp;
    features=undefined&amp;
    disabled_features=undefined" 
    width="700" height="550" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
```